# How can I hide a span if an input field is valid with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I can do this:

```
 <span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">Problem</span>
```

but I have a number of different possible errors so is there a way I can hide the span if the field is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$valid` property of the form.

```
<span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer && ! form.size.$valid">Problem</span>
```

But Im not sure why you need this. If there is no error, `form.size.$error.integer` should be false and it should be hidden anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $valid property, such us:

```
   <span ng-hide="form.size.$valid">Problem</span>
```